# Using width vs using min-width & max-width

Tags: css, flexbox

What is the best way to use the css width parameters when trying to keep an element at a set constant width even when the width of the page changes?

(i.e `width: 20rem; & min-width: 20rem;` vs `min-width: 20rem; & max-width: 20rem;`)

**Using just** `width: 20rem;` **results in the sidebar shrinking from a change in width:**

Expected width of the sidebar:

[image: Expected width of the sidebar]

---

Sidebar shrinks when I would like it to remain the same size:

[image: Sidebar shrinks when I would like it to remain the same size]

---

**However using** `width: 20rem; & min-width: 20rem;` **seems to solve this issue.**

Expected width of the sidebar:

[image: Expected width of the sidebar]

---

Expected width of the sidebar remains:

[image: Expected width of the sidebar remains]

---

**Also using** `min-width: 20rem; & max-width: 20rem;` **seems to also solve this issue.**

Expected width using max-width:

[image: Expected width using max-width]

---

Expected width using max-width even when window size changes:

[image: Expected width using max-width even when window size changes]

My overall question is which solution is preferred and what are the consequences of each as they both seem relatively the same

General css code

```
.messages-component {

    .threads-sidebar {
        @include box-shadow-helper(1);
        background: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 20rem;

        .threads-sidebar-header {
            @include box-shadow-helper(1);
            display: flex;
            min-height: 3em;
        }

        .threads-sidebar-body {
            @include box-shadow-helper(1);
            display: flex;
            flex: 1;
            flex-direction: column;

            .test {
                color: $mvn-btn-red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Min-width and max-width specify constraints on how large/small a resizable object can go. So if you want your element to not be resizable you should just use a constant width by using pixels(px) instead of rem.

Comment: Is it preferred to use px in this case? I've been told to always use rem or em since these units perform better when scaling displays.

Comment: That's true if you want the component to scale, but here it seems like you don't. The concern with using px is that it breaks pretty quickly with different screen sizes though, so you may want to follow max-width using @Jason Smith's answer. That way your component will still scale down without expanding like you're seeing in the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Width and min-width can work together. Most people use two different units when using them example: width: 90%, min-width:600px. It is also worth noting that min-width will overide width.

[W3 min-width](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp)