# Why do we include both width and max-width declarations in CSS?

Tags: html, css, width

Is there any difference between declaring both `width` and `max-width` and declaring only one?

As I have understood, using only the `max-width` property causes all of an element's content to be fit dynamically when the viewport is resized.

Comment: sometimes when you can set width with percentage and you want to set max-width with certain absolute value. it depends on your use case.

Comment: Hi perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381391/using-width-vs-using-min-width-max-width

Comment: It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming larger than the value specified by max-width

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following pen, feel free to resize the window to see what happens:https://codepen.io/harrison-rood/pen/KKzPQMW

The first example is an image with an explicit width of 800px.

The second is an image with a max-width of 800px, but a width of 100%.

See how one is responsive and the other is not? In the first example, we're telling the image it needs to be exactly 800px. In the second example, we're saying that the image should be a fluid 100%, but not any bigger than 800px, no matter what.

You can also use this idea in reverse. The third example has an image with a width of `auto` (as big as possible) but a max width of 100%, meaning that it will be as big as its container, but not overflow out of it.

The fourth example shows what would happen without max width. See how the image stretches way past its container because it is much larger?

Hope this clears things up! If it does, be sure to leave an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Using `max-width`, as the name implies, means that, when a container contains more content than it can fit, its width won't exceed the specified `max-width`.

`max-width` is specifically used to prevent a container's width from increasing when it contains more content than it can fit—instead, when `max-width` is specified, the content will overflow out of the container.

Comment: In the case of a browser window which is the container and which is the content?my apologies for my dummy questions but im new in html and css and i wanna understand whats going on..

Comment: The container is any element with other elements or plain text inside. The content is the other elements or plain text.

Answer (score 0):

This is because screen resolutions can be different sizes. Lets say you have an element with a width of `15%`, if you increase your window width, 15% becomes larger in pixels. You can set a max-width from preventing it from going over a certain width in pixels.

Comment: While this is on the right track, I think this use case is more concisely and idiomatically written as `width: max(<percentage>, <absolute>)`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max) for more info on `max()` in CSS.